# Delete META-INF folder

Tags: java, meta-inf

I need remove `jarFile.jar`  > `/META-INF`   folder.

First, I extract the original `jarFile.jar` into `temp/ folder`

Then I delete `META-INF/`

And zip it again, no errors, but the file appears corrupt.

Anyone can help me?

EDIT:

> ```
> public static void removeJarFiles(File jarFile, String[] files) throws IOException {
>     File tempFolder = new File(jarFile.getParentFile(), "temp/");
>     tempFolder.mkdirs();
>     unZip(jarFile.getAbsolutePath(), tempFolder.getAbsolutePath()); // Decompress JAR
>     // Delete files
>     for (String file : files) {
>         File f = new File(tempFolder, file);
>         if (f.isDirectory()) {
>             Util.deleteDir(f);
>         } else {
>             if (f.exists()) {
>                 f.delete();
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     jarFile.delete(); // Delete OLD Jar
>     // Re-Create JAR
>     zipFolder(tempFolder.getAbsolutePath(), jarFile.getAbsolutePath());
> }
> ```

Comment: This.. isn't really a programming issue.

Comment: I think it's because I can not compile a .JAR with ZIP

Comment: what do you mean by 'corrupt'?

Comment: java -jar temp.jar
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile temp.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove META-INF from a jar then there is no MANIFEST.MF and so java -jar can't find the main class.

You can create jars without META-INF but when you are going to execute a jar a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is required.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html